# NEED SUGGESTION: How to write a Microsoft Outlook Add-In that can select multiple GROUPS(folders) of contacts all at once?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in, contacts, outlook-2007

I'm trying to write an Outlook 2007 Add-In that can let me **select multiple groups(folders) of contacts** to send e-mails to all recipients at once.

My Outlook contacts are grouped into several folders(groups). By default, Microsoft Outlook does not have the functionality to let users send e-mails to all groups of contacts by simply choosing a “select all” function from a menu at once. Instead, Outlook only allows you to select multiple contacts within one folder.

Any idea how/where I can get started?
I have looked the MSDN site ([Outlook Solutions with Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/vsto/dd162450.aspx)) but does not know how to begin?

**or is this any other good tutorial/reference website I can use for reference?**

Answer (score 0):

After selection the groups you wish to email...

In Outlook 2007 you can use the icon "New Message to Contact" (*following the delete button in the commandbar*). You can also use the menubar (Actions->Create->New Message to Contact).

In Outlook 2010, you can click "Email" under the Home->Communicate ribbon group.

Comment: your answer does no help at all.
How do you select multiple contact folders?

Comment: Snow - my misunderstanding, I thought you were talking about contact groups (i.e. distribution lists, email groups). The terminology is sometimes misleading with groups of folders and group of contacts. It sounds like there is no native support for this, you would need a custom plugin to select multiple outlook folders within the navigation pane.

Comment: yup, custom plug-in is exactly what I'm trying to do.
just wondering if anyone has any resources specially related to this section.